# Summing Values in a Ruby Array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am attempting to sum an array of averaged integers.

I have the following classes in my helper with an example of an array they return:

```
def day_of_week_yard_activity
    YardActivity.group_by_day_of_week(:date, format: "%A").joins(:line_transactions)
end

def full_deliver_avg
   day_of_week_yard_activity.average(:full_deliver).map { |d,n| [d, n.to_f.round]}
end
def full_recieve_avg
   day_of_week_yard_activity.average(:full_recieve).map { |d,n| [d, n.to_f.round]}
end
def empty_recieve_avg
   day_of_week_yard_activity.average(:empty_recieve).map { |d,n| [d, n.to_f.round]}
end
def empty_deliver_avg
   day_of_week_yard_activity.average(:empty_deliver).map { |d,n| [d, n.to_f.round]}
end => [["Sunday", 0], ["Monday", 1], ["Tuesday", 2], ["Wednesday", 1], ["Thursday", 2], ["Friday", 1], ["Saturday", 0]]
```

I have tried the following to group each by the position [0] and sum the [1] position together but am on receiving random position [0] back:

```
  def averaged_summed_total_transactions
    [full_deliver_avg, full_recieve_avg, full_deliver_avg, empty_deliver_avg].group_by(&:first).map { |d,n| [d, n.map(&:last).inject(:+)]}
  end
=> [[["Sunday", 0], ["Saturday", 0, "Saturday", 0, "Saturday", 0, "Saturday", 0]]]
```

What I am expecting is to receive an array similar to the following:

```
[["Sunday", 0], ["Monday", 4], ["Tuesday", 8], ["Wednesday", 4], ["Thursday", 8], ["Friday", 4], ["Saturday", 0]]
```

I think I am misunderstanding the `group_by(&:first)` and/or `(&:last).inject(:+)`.

Comment: Maybe you want to provide more clearly the input data and the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to,

```
obj = arrays.flatten.each_slice(2).with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |slice, obj| 
  obj[slice[0]] += slice[1]
end.to_a
```